# Way to view, filter, and sort database tables in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am building an app for my work in Django (they are having me learn it on my own). I need to display a database table with filter/search criteria above it, along with clickable columns to sort the rows by these fields. There are thousands of rows, so I also need some pagination. Again, I am brand new to Django, so I have the feeling that there is already a lot of existing functionality for this type of thing, I'm just not sure how to find it, or even what I am looking for exactly. Am I looking for an app to install? A built-in template? Something not related to Django but to something else? I want something VERY similar to the ModelAdmin template - almost identical, in fact, though I've heard that is not really reusable. Any pointers would be wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems you are looking for datatables.

Check [django-datatable-view](https://github.com/pivotal-energy-solutions/django-datatable-view) and [django-datatable](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable)

Comment: Thanks! this seems useful. Is this something I could use with django-filter? Or does it offer the same functionality?

Comment: If you use django-filter extensively you may combine it with django-tables2. Check this post. http://kuttler.eu/post/using-django-tables2-filters-crispy-forms-together/